# perl regex: how to make regex match all strings in the file (that has only one line)

Tags: regex, perl

How can I tell perl regexp to go through the whole line repeatedly?

My file (test) contents is this and all the data is in one line only. The real file is much bigger but again all the data is in one line.

```
{"abc":"283420","def":"283420"},{"abc":"483420","def":"253420"},{"abc":"283120","def":"284420"}
```

I would like to perl print this:

```
283420,283420
483420,253420
283120,284420
```

My current code:

```
perl -nle 'print "$1,$2"  while( /.*abc\":\"(\d*)\".*def\":\"(\d+)/g)' test
```

prints only the last match

```
283120,284420
```

Comment: REGEX are not the right tool, use a JSON parser instead

Comment: Try to have a different name insted of `test`. `test` could be a system built-in and it could generate unwanted behaviour (even if it doesn't currently in your scenario). Better to be safe with this.

Comment: sputnick, I have files of sizes going up to 2 Gigabytes. Can you recommend JSON parser that can do that ? I think perl is quite efficient here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl regexes are "greedy", which means that they try to match as many characters as possible. Your first `.*` therefore matches everything up to but not including the last `abc` on the line, so you only get the last numbers. To tell a quantifier to match the least number of characters you need to put a question mark after it.

```
perl -nle 'print "$1,$2"  while( /.*?abc\":\"(\d*)\".*?def\":\"(\d+)/g)' test
```

Comment: that was fast, fantastic. Thanks!

Comment: sputnik's comment is a good one. This is JSON, so a JSON parser is probably best.